# if array contains duplicate, merge both values as one

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

I've got an array that looks like:

[image]

Is there a way that when another object "AAPL" gets added to the array, the fees and amount gets added and AAPL stays one object in the array?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes, you can write code to do this. Stack Overflow can help with your existing code if it doesn't work correctly but won't write your code for you.

Comment: The answer to your question is, "yes, there is a way". You can either try to figure it out on your own by improving your understanding of functions and the Array prototype or ask/pay someone to solve the problem for you. Stackoverflow isn't the place however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't want to assume that "AAPL" is always within the array.

Check first if the new item is within the array. If not, I will return and end the call (but you may wish to append this to the array instead as it is a new item).

If it is, replace the current object (or parts of the object, in this case I have done just fees & amount)

```
function addPortfolioItem(item) {
    const index = returnPortfolioHoldingIndex(item);
    if (index = -1) {
        // Returning if not found - You may wish to append to the array as mentioned above
        return;
    } else {
        // Overwrite the object within the array with the new object
        portfolioHoldings[index].fees = item.fees;
        portfolioHoldings[index].amount = item.amount;
    }
}

function returnPortfolioHoldingIndex() {
    const tickerSymbolToSearch = "AAPL";
    return portfolioHoldings.findIndex(item => item.ticker_symbol === tickerSymbolToSearch);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed. You're right, AAPL is not always in the array. But could you help me rewrite it? Sorry maybe I had to be clear with my code. I'm using GraphQl to obtain the array.

 const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(PORTFOLIO_HOLDINGS);

which logs the screenshot above.

Would I have to use "data" instead of item?

Comment: The function parameter name can be anything, but you should call the function with data from what you're describing. addPortfolioItem(data); This function call will copy the value of data into item, alternatively you can rename this data. Please accept the answer if it resolves your issue!

Answer (score 0):

First identify the entry then just add another integer to the value.

It depends on how you are updating that object now - if it's always in 0 position then just portfolioHoldings[0][amount] += number;

if not, then loop through all and check if ticker_symbol == AAPL, then update that array value, by adding needed amount.